# How can I convert a Java HashSet<Integer> to a primitive int array?

Tags: java, arrays, int, hashset

I've got a `HashSet<Integer>` with a bunch of `Integers` in it. I want to turn it into an array, but calling

```
hashset.toArray();
```

returns an `Object[]`. Is there a better way to cast it to an array of `int` other than iterating through every element manually?  I want to pass the array to

```
void doSomething(int[] arr)
```

which won't accept the Object[] array, even if I try casting it like

```
doSomething((int[]) hashSet.toArray());
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Apache's [ArrayUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html) has this (it still iterates [behind the scenes](https://github.com/apache/commons-lang/blob/LANG_3_2_RC1/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.java)):

```
doSomething(ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(hashset.toArray()));
```

They're always a good place to check for things like this.

Comment: Automatic +1 for recommending Apache Commons.

Comment: @skaffman I'd recommend Apache Commons Lang ... not for this particular problem though ... but anyway, make your move ;)

Comment: Actually, it doesn't iterate behind the scenes - it iterates twice. There is an unnecessary `Integer[]` that slows down the process of creating a primitive array from a collection. Actually, I think the choice to use `Integer[]` as parameter for `toPrimitive(..)` instead of `Iterable<Integer>` is a bit clunky as `Arrays.asList(Integer[])` is a much faster operation than `collection.toArray()`. Hence I won't automatically +1 for recommending apache commons :)

Comment: sfussenegger, Apache Commons (what I meant by "it") only iterates once.  You're right that the creation of the array requires an iteration.

Comment: I though so but still wanted to emphasize it (the -1 wasn't from me btw)

Comment: I can only get this to work if I use `ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(hashset.toArray( new Integer[hashset.size()]))`

Comment: @sfussenegger actually, the code as written in the answer produces an `Object[]`, so it doesn’t even work. You would need `ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(hashset.toArray(new Integer[0]))`, to make it the inefficient solution that it is supposed to be.

Answer (score 40):

You can create an `int[]` from any `Collection<Integer>` (including a `HashSet<Integer>`) using Java 8 streams:

```
int[] array = coll.stream().mapToInt(Number::intValue).toArray();
```

The library is still iterating over the collection (or other stream source) on your behalf, of course.

In addition to being concise and having no external library dependencies, streams also let you go parallel if you have a really big collection to copy.

Comment: A bit more concise: int[] array = coll.stream().mapToInt(x -> x).toArray()

Answer (score 9):

Try this.
Using java 8.

```
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
    set.add(43);
    set.add(423);
    set.add(11);
    set.add(44);
    set.add(56);
    set.add(422);
    set.add(34);
    int[] arr = set.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
```

Answer (score 8):

You can convert a `Set<Integer>` to `Integer[]` even without Apache Utils:

```
Set<Integer> myset = new HashSet<Integer>();
Integer[] array = myset.toArray(new Integer[0]);
```

However, if you need `int[]` you have to iterate over the set.

Answer (score 5):

*Note: This answer is outdated, use `Stream.mapToInt(..)`*

```
public int[] toInt(Set<Integer> set) {
  int[] a = new int[set.size()];
  int i = 0;
  for (Integer val : set) {
    // treat null as 0
    a[i++] = val == null ? 0 : val;
  }
  return a;
}
```

Now that I wrote the code for you it's not that manual anymore, is it? ;)

Comment: It wasn't that writing the code to do it manually was a problem, I was just curious to see if there was a better way to do it.

Comment: Well, the essence of my answer was that the only way to avoid writing this code is getting others to write it (but actually that's the case for just about any code) - which you successfully did ;)

Comment: Can you put null in a Set<Integer>? If so, this code will NPE. I'm not sure what the original poster would want to do with nulls though. I guess omit them from the resulting array.

Comment: @davidsheldon Valid remark. You may put null into a Set<Integer> if the implementation supports it (obviously, yes, but that's what Set's Javadoc defines). HashSet and TreeMap will throw a NPE when trying to add null. Throwing a NPE in case set contains null seems to be the way to go though, of course along with appropriate documentation of this behavior - we all document thoroughly, don't we ;)

Comment: Not quiet correct. `HashSet` allows `null` and `TreeSet` will allow `null` if a custom `Comparator` which can deal with `null` has been specified. But it’s true that the best behavior is to just let the code throw a `NullPointerException` if the set contains `null`.

Answer (score 4):

You can just use Guava's:

```
Ints.toArray(Collection<? extends Number> collection)
```

Answer (score 2):

Nope; you've got to iterate over them.  Sorry.

Comment: It makes sense if you think about it. ints aren't objects, so typecasting one to the other doesn't work.

Comment: It seems odd that you can't get an array of ints from a HashSet of Integers though, shouldn't the autoboxing kick in and allow you to do it? It's not like the HashSet contains a mixture of types, they're all Integers so (as far as I can see), it wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Collections can only hold objects (Integers in your case).  Thus, it would be odd to have a special method to get an array of ints (corresponding methods would be required for other primitive types).  Auto-boxing doesn't help, because that only applies for a single primitive<->object conversion.  Keep in mind that the actual class (due to type erasure) is HashSet, not HashSet<Integer> (only a compile-time concept).

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen wouldn't type erasure cause the actual class to be HashSet<Object>?  -http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Answer (score -4):

You could also use the toArray(T[] contents) variant of the toArray() method.  Create an empty array of ints of the same size as the HashSet, and then pass it to the toArray() method:

```
Integer[] myarray = new Integer[hashset.size()];
doSomething(hashset.toArray(myarray));
```

You'd have to change the `doSomething()` function to accept an `Integer[]` array instead of `int[]`.  If that is not feasible, you'd have convert the array of values returned by `toArray` to `int[]`.

Comment: It would help to provide your compile errors so I can tell what's wrong with my code.

Comment: Why don't you just try compiling it yourself? Once you see the compile error, I can explain you why it happened.